# Read JSON web token in http header after backend SAML2 authentication

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt, saml-2.0

I want to read the JWT from the http header in my angular application after an redirect from my backend, but I can't figure out how. This is my authentication process:

1. after successful login of the user in the web browser, there is a POST request to the application backend
2. backend (spring boot) verifies SAML2 data and creates a JSON web token
3. backend attaches the token to the http response and redirects to /angular-login (http status code 302)
4. angular bootstraps, but I can't figure out how to get the JWT from the http header

Do you have any better ideas? Note that I can only change stuff after step 2.

As a last resort I could temporarily store the token in a cookie or into the url as parameter, but that does not seem to be a clean solution.

Comment: can you confirm that your token gets attached in response?

Comment: Yes, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameters that you get from the remote system via cookie or path variable to the frontend as JWT (in the 3rd step)

Comment: How can I store the token as a cookie instead of getting it as a POST response in the 302 redirect page ?